# How can i check if $varA contains $varB?

Tags: string, bash, shell, if-statement, grep

I have a variable `$user` and `$remotequota`. `$user` contains a string and `$remotequota` is a file located on the disk.

I want to check if the string `$user` is also in the file which is stored in `$remotequota`

Have tried it with several versions of `if grep -q $user "$remotequota"` and also with `if grep -q $user <<<$remotequota`

The strange thing is that sometimes i get the results i want (have double-checked) and then i don't. This is driving me crayz

Is there a better way to check a if `$varA` contains `$varB`?

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to check a if `$varA` contains `$varB`:

This should be:

```
[[ $varA == *"$varB"* ]]
```

However if `$varA` is a filename then use `grep`:

```
grep -iF "$varB" "$varA"
```

Note use of `-F` to treat value of `varB` as fixed string and use of quotes.